# Adding noise to an image in increments

Tags: python, image, noise

Hi I am trying to add noise to a QR image that I create, this is my code so far:

```
import numpy
import scipy
import scipy.misc
import sys
sys.path.append('M:/PythonMods')
import qrcode

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myqr = qrcode.make("randomtexxxxxxxxxt")
    #myqr.show()
    myqr.save("M:/COMPUTINGSEMESTER2/myqr4.png") 


filename = 'myqr4.png'

imagea = (scipy.misc.imread(filename)).astype(float)

poissonNoise = numpy.random.poisson(50,imagea.shape).astype(float)

noisyImage = imagea + poissonNoise
```

Please could someone advise me how I get it to show the noisy image? and how to save the image so I can test it?

Any help really appreciated.

edit

I tried adding this code to the program to get it to show the image:

```
from PIL import Image
myimage = Image.open(noisyImage)
myimage.load()
```

But then got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:\COMPUTINGSEMESTER2\untitled4.py", line 28, in <module>
    myimage = Image.open(noisyImage)
  File "Q:\PythonXY273_MaPS-T.v01\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1958, in open
    prefix = fp.read(16)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Image.open` needs an image file as parameter, use `Image.fromarray`:

```
im = Image.fromarray(noisyImage)
im.save("myFile.jpeg")
```

you may also use `matplotlib` module to show the image directly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(noisyImage) #Needs to be in row,col order
```

Comment: thankyou for the help with saving the image. im unsure of the next part, i would like to show the changed image, what's matrix? thanks again for the post

Comment: i did this: im = Image.fromarray(noisyImage) im.show(noisyImage) and it worked!! im amazed that something actually works!! it doesnt put the noise anywhere near the image, but its something to work with. thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
scipy.misc.imsave('NoisyImage.jpg', noisyImage)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, it says this when i include the above: NameError: name 'image_array' is not defined

Comment: Just change the name to the name of the array you created, i.e. `noisyImage`